# Submit form from page#1 to iframe page#2 within page#3 and load page#3

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, submit

I have a form on my page#1 which I need to be submitted to page#2 which is an iframe within page#3. 
I can submit from page#1 to iframe with bellow code but what I need is when I submit on page#1 to load page#3 which will load submitted form iframe.

Here is the form from page#1
target="/search.html" represents the page#3 link but does not load. Instead it loads iframe on separate window.

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="search-results/" target="/search.html" method="post">

<input type="text"  name="keywords[all_words]" />

<input type="text"  name="City[all_words]" />

<a href="#" class="btn_search row_right" onclick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit()">Search</a>
```

Comment: It is not possible with your current approach; because, first you want to navigate to `page 3` which have a `iframe` that includes the page in which you want to submit your request. Any server side language you are using like `php` or something like that?